# Rails conditional validation with two submit buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make a page that allows users to create events. I want them to be able to save the event first, which will put it in the database but not allow other users to see it. I also want to allow the user to publish the event, which will prevent them from making more changes and allow other users to see it.

I planned on doing this by having both "Save" and "Publish" buttons on the create event form. Because saving it means that it's still incomplete, I don't really need to validate anything when this button is clicked, but I do when the "Publish" button is clicked.

I tried to accomplish this with the following code in event.rb, but the validation is executing when either button is clicked.

```
with_options :if => :published? do
  validates_date :date, presence: true, :after => Time.now, :after_message => 'must be in the future'
  validates_time :time, presence: true
end

def published?
  :published == "true"
end
```

I've confirmed that :published should only equal "true" when the publish button is clicked. (I'm setting event[published] to true via JS when the user clicks "publish". It defaults to false otherwise.)

Any idea why the validation is always executing?

EDIT: I'm still not sure why this didn't work, but I did find that it worked as expected if I did the check on each of the validates clauses individually, as follows:

```
validates_date :date, presence: true, :after => lambda { Time.now }, :after_message => 'must be in the future', :if => :published?
validates_time :time, presence: true, :if => :published?
```

Answer (score 2):

you may have a typo here use published == "true" instead of :published == "true"

```
def published?
    self.published == "true"
end
```

I also noticed you use (:after => Time.now). I think that on production this line will only be evaluated once. so you may want to use a lambda somehow to make sure that Time.now is always called when validating